# How to separate pin when I connect USB?

Tags: embedded, switching, fet

I'm working on BL653 project, I have an issue how to left VDD_HV pin unconnected when I'm using USB?
VDD_HV pin must be unconnected because I am using OPTION 1 with USB.
OPTION 1 says that both VDD and VDD_HV pins must be on same voltage suply(in my case 3.3V).[image: usb with bl653]

Comment: The datasheet for the embedded Bluetooth chip, nRF52833, does not list an "OPTION 1" . Please provide link to the datasheet you're using. Are you trying to power the module only from the USB connection? Or do you have an internal battery or other power supply?

Comment: I download data sheet from here https://gr.mouser.com/Laird-Connectivity/Embedded-Solutions/Wireless-RF-Modules/Bluetooth-Modules-802151/BL653-Series/Datasheets/_/N-6l7pg?P=1y7w27dZ1y8g6p5 And I use other power suplay(from MikroBUS).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Sava.

You've correctly implemented Option 1 in your schematic. As long as you are using an internal supply within the range of 1.7 to 3.6 VDC, VDD_HV and VDD are connected together, and fed with your internal power supply.

You also have VBUS correctly connected to the USB receptacle VBUS pin.

Option 2 is for internal power supplies, or USB power sources, in the 5 V range (3.6 to 5.5 VDC). In this mode, you would feed VDD_HV and leave VDD unconnected.

There is no mode where VDD_HV is left floating.

Edit: Here is the table 14 in the latest version of the datasheet (see link in OP):
[image: table 14 of datasheet]

The "Yes" and "No" indicates which pin (Vdd or Vdd_hv) is the primary power feed pin. I believe the "Note 1" footnote should have been included in column 3, just as in column 1, to indicate you tie VDD and VDD_HV together and feed them from your 3.3 V supply.

If you still are concerned -- and good for you, for not believing everything you hear on the Internet -- you should contact the manufacturer's support team for confirmation of your design.

Comment: If you look in datasheet on page 25, when using option 1 and USB, VDD_HV pin can't support voltage between 2.5V and 5.5V(Table 14), in my schematic it is always on 3.3V.